# Combining Analytic Functions with Rollup

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am able to get aggregation subtotals by using `GROUP BY ROLLUP` and I am able to get `% of Parent` and other similar calculations using analytic functions, i.e., `OVER()`. However, I'm having a hard-time combining these two. For example, trying to get the % of Parent for Profit in the below:

```
with SalesX as (
    select 'Office Supplies' Category , 2014 Year,22593.42 Profit UNION all
    select 'Technology', 2014, 21492.83 UNION all
    select 'Furniture', 2014,   5457.73 UNION all
    select 'Office Supplies',   2015,   25099.53  UNION all
    select 'Technology',    2015,   33503.87  UNION all
    select 'Furniture', 2015,   50000.00  UNION all
    select 'Office Supplies',   2016,   35061.23  UNION all
    select 'Technology',    2016,   39773.99  UNION all
    select 'Furniture', 2016,   6959.95
) 
select category, year, Profit, SUM(Profit) OVER (partition by category)
from (
SELECT
    category,
    year,
    SUM(profit) Profit
FROM SalesX group by rollup(category, year) order by category
) _
```

Here we can see it 'double counts' because of the rollups:

[image]

What would be the proper way to fix this?

Comment: It would be very helpful to also see what the actual expected output is here.  Otherwise, it may not be clear to everyone what you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yea agreed. I was having a hard time writing up what I wanted to get as I'm going from Excel to try and copy a feature in a query. I've posted an answer though of what I used.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sure please post an answer.

Answer (score -1):

BigQuery doesn't support the `GROUPING` function to see if an aggregated value is a subtotal, but assuming the `NULL` value always represents a total, we can string together various `CASE`s to exclude the subtotal rows:

```
with SalesX as (
    select 'Office Supplies' Category , 2014 Year,22593.42 Profit UNION all
    select 'Technology', 2014, 21492.83 UNION all
    select 'Furniture', 2014,   5457.73 UNION all
    select 'Office Supplies',   2015,   25099.53  UNION all
    select 'Technology',    2015,   33503.87  UNION all
    select 'Furniture', 2015,   50000.00  UNION all
    select 'Office Supplies',   2016,   35061.23  UNION all
    select 'Technology',    2016,   39773.99  UNION all
    select 'Furniture', 2016,   6959.95
) 
select category, year, Profit,
    Profit / SUM(CASE WHEN category is null or year is null then null else Profit end) OVER (partition by category) as CategoryPercent,
    Profit / SUM(CASE WHEN category is null or year is null then null else Profit end) OVER () as GrandPercent
from (
SELECT
    category,
    year,
    SUM(profit) Profit
FROM SalesX group by rollup(category, year) order by category
) _
```

This gives us what we're looking for:

[image]